# View function did not return a response

Tags: python, sql, flask

I want to send a query to mysql and fetch an array. But however I do it I cannot make it work. Here's my code:

```
@app.route('/auth',methods=['GET','POST'])
def auth(): 
    username = request.form['username']
    password = request.form['password']

    cur = db.cursor() 
    cur.execute("SELECT * FROM tbl_user WHERE username = '%s' " % username)

    results = cur.fetchall()

    for row in results:
        print row[0]
```

It always says, `view function did not return a response`. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: 1) Fix the indentation in your posted code and 2) run the same query in your DB and see what that says

Comment: Please give us the full traceback, and the web framework you are using.

Comment: @MartijnPieters I'm taking a stab at Flask and MySQL :)

Comment: @JonClements: What if `view` refers to the `auth` method...

Comment: i use flask,you are right i should delete GET method

Comment: This is not a MySQL problem but a Flask problem..

Comment: and i haven't taken sql error,it only says 

ValueError: View function did not return a response

Comment: @MartijnPieters yes ur absolutely right

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Flask throws this exception because your `auth` view didn't return anything. Return a response from your `auth` view:

```
return 'Some response'
```

To return the MySQL results, perhaps join the rows together into one string:

```
cur.execute("SELECT * FROM tbl_user WHERE username = '%s' " % username)
return '\n'.join([', '.join(r) for r in cur])
```

or define a template and [return the rendered template](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/quickstart/#rendering-templates).

Note that you really do not want to use string interpolation for your `username` parameter, *especially* in a web application. Use SQL parameters instead:

```
cur.execute("SELECT * FROM tbl_user WHERE username = %s", (username,))
```

Now the database client will do the quoting for you and prevent SQL injection attacks. If you use string interpolation, [this will happen](http://xkcd.com/327/).

(If this was a decent database (e.g. not MySQL) the database could take the now-generic SQL statement and create a query plan for it, then reuse the plan again and again as you execute that query multiple times; using string interpolation you'd prevent that.)

Comment: @Gandalf you seem new to this - I would recommend you use an ORM - this will make life much easier - have a read of http://packages.python.org/Flask-SQLAlchemy/

Comment: yes im beginner with python,i will take your advise,thank you :)

Comment: Indeed I do! I want me some Little Bobby Tables here.

Comment: i still solve my problem.What i want to do is,compare post data with the row in database.So i should send a query with given username and have the results,than compare the passwords.But can not do anything with sql results.Can anyone help

Comment: @Gandalf: We are straying into 'too broad` territory here. You need to find yourself a good tutorial on Python and SQL queries instead.